# right align property not working while giving width to tds

Tags: java, css, jsp

I am having a jsp and some jspf in which I want short,long mid term fields as well as heading to be right aligned but it is not working as soon as I remove the width property
from my style right align start working.Although the style is working in one of the included
jsp, but not working the jsp which is including all the other jspf and a jsp.

the jsp which is including other jspf and a jsp is something like------

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
</script> 
</head>
<body class="dashboard">
<html-el:form action="${form.formAction}">
<div id="scrollHeader">     
    <html-el:hidden property="selectedForecastUnitOID"/>    
    <html-el:hidden property="selectedFactoryOID"/> 
        <%@ include file="ViewInputHeader.jspf"%>     
        <%@ include file="Error.jspf"%>
</div>
<div id="scrollBody">
<!-- **** BEGIN MESSAGE AREA **** -->
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
</table>
<!-- NOTE: expand/collapse functionality needs to be added to this screen. Tables were used to allow the columns to align.
    This may not be the best approach for the actual implementation.
 -->
<table class="dashboard">
    <COLGROUP class="dashRowLabel" span="1" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep1" span="1" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep2" span="3" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep3" span="4" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep4" span="4" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep5" span="1" />
    <thead>
        <tr class="stepRow">
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['STEP1']}</th>
            <th colspan="3">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['STEP2']}</th>
            <th colspan="4">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['STEP3']}</th>          
        </tr>
        <TR class="stepLabel">
    <th rowspan=2 class="headerLineName"></th> 
    <th rowspan=2class="stepOne">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS'ABBR_COE']}</th>
    <th rowspan=2 class="stepTwo">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['ABBR_MKT']}</th>
    <th rowspan=2 class="stepTwo">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['ABBR_PDC']}</th>
    <th rowspan=2 class="stepTwo">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['ABBR_SPO']}</th>
    <th rowspan=2 class="stepOne">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['MEETING']}</th>
    <th colspan="3" class="spanLabel">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['COMPOSITE_ADJ']}</th>            
        </TR>
        <TR class="stepLabel numeric">
        <th class="termValues">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['TERM_SHORT']}</th>
        <th class="termValues">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['TERM_MID']}</th>
        <th class="termValues">${PAGE_TRANSLATION_KEYS['TERM_LONG']}</th>           
        </TR>
    </thead>
</table> 

<c:forEach items="${form.sbus}" var="sbu" varStatus="id">
        <DIV class=section>
        <DIV class="title collapsable" id="SBU${sbu.sbuOID}"> ${sbu.sbuName}
            <%@ include file="SbuSummaryIndicators.jspf"%>      
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="content positioning">
    <c:forEach items="${sbu.forecastUnits}" var="forecastUnit" varStatus="forecastid">
            <DIV class=section>
                <DIV class="title collapsable" id="FU${forecastUnit.forecastUnitOID}">${forecastUnit.forecastUnitID}
                <%@ include file="ForecastUnitSummaryIndicators.jspf"%>
                </DIV>
                <DIV class="content factoryPositioning">
    <c:forEach items="${forecastUnit.factories}" var="factory" varStatus="factoryid">
                        <DIV class=section>
                            <DIV class="title collapsed expandableFactory ajaxExpand" id="DR${forecastUnit.forecastUnitOID}_${factory.factoryOID}">(${factory.factoryID}) ${factory.factoryName}
            <%@ include file="FactorySummaryIndicators.jspf"%>                      
            </DIV>
              <DIV class="content">
            </DIV>  
        </DIV>                      
        </c:forEach>
        </DIV>
        </DIV>
        </c:forEach>
        </DIV>
        </DIV>
</c:forEach>

</div>

</html-el:form>
</body>
</html-el:html>
```

One of the jspf which is included is like ---

```
<table> 
    <COLGROUP class="dashRowLabel" span="1" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep1" span="1" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep2" span="3" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep3" span="4" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep4" span="4" />
    <COLGROUP class="dashStep5" span="1" />

    <tr class="dashProductLine">
        <td class="productLineName"><html-el:text property="form.sbus[${id.count}].sbuName" styleClass="textSize textColor" readonly="true" value=" "/></td>

        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.demandPlanning=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.demandPlanning=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.demandPlanning=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
<c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.demandPlanning=='3' || compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='5'}">
        <td class="statusCompleted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.marketing=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.marketing=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.marketing=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.marketing=='3' || sbu.sbuSummary.marketing=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.analyst=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.analyst=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.analyst=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.analyst=='3' || sbu.sbuSummary.analyst=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.spo=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.spo=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.spo=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.spo=='3' || sbu.sbuSummary.spo=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.meeting=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.meeting=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.meeting=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.meeting=='3' || sbu.sbuSummary.meeting=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepOne"></td>
        </c:if>

        <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.shortCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${sbu.sbuSummary.shortCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>
        <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.midCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${sbu.sbuSummary.midCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>
        <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${sbu.sbuSummary.longCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${sbu.sbuSummary.longCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>
    </tr>
</table>
```

although the jsp where it is working is like----

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  
<%response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pages/dashboard.css" type="text/css">
<%@ include file="Error.jspf"%> 
<table class="dashboard">
    <c:forEach items="${viewDashboardForm.compositeProcessStatusList}" var="compositeProcessStatus">
        <tr class="dashProductLine">
                    <td class="name viewDashboard">${compositeProcessStatus.productLineName}</td>

            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='0'}">
                <td class="statusWaiting stepOne"></td>
                    </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepOne"></td>
                    </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepOne"></td>
                    </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='3' ||  compositeProcessStatus.demandPlanning=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepOne"></td>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.marketing=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
                    </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.marketing=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.marketing=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.marketing=='3' || compositeProcessStatus.marketing=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.analyst=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.analyst=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.analyst=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.analyst=='3' || compositeProcessStatus.analyst=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.spo=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.spo=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.spo=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.spo=='3' || compositeProcessStatus.spo=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepTwo"></td>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.meeting=='0'}">
            <td class="statusWaiting stepOne"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.meeting=='1'}">
            <td class="statusNotStarted stepOne"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.meeting=='2'}">
            <td class="statusStarted stepOne"></td>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.meeting=='3' || compositeProcessStatus.meeting=='5'}">
            <td class="statusCompleted stepOne"></td>
            </c:if>

            <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.shortCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${compositeProcessStatus.shortCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>
            <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.midCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${compositeProcessStatus.midCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>
                <TD class="numeric termValues"><c:if test="${compositeProcessStatus.longCompositeAmount != '0'}" >${compositeProcessStatus.longCompositeAmount}</c:if></TD>             
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

the style which is not applying is termValues which is applied in the header field 
of the jsp which is including other as well as the included files, it is working in the 
included jsp but not in the jsp including all the others as well not in the included jspfs.

the style is

```
.termValues{
    width: 6em;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Please see instructions for Markdown formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your table-layout to fixed. This usually fixes any issues I have with columns not lining up.

```
table
{
     table-layout:fixed;
}
```